# Chef multiple level attribute file override with role JSON

Tags: json, ruby, chef-infra

I have an attributes file that looks like this:

```
default['ftp_provision']['vsftpd']['pasv_ip']                = "192.168.0.10"
```

where the first attribute is the cookbook name, the second is the program, and the third is the option I want to change, implemented in a template .erb file as:

```
pasv_ip=<%node['ftp_provision']['vsftpd']['pasv_ip']%>
```

This is working correctly as expected.
However, I would like to add a role to change these attributes as required for several nodes. I'm using `knife role create ftp_node1` to do that doing something like:

```
"default_attributes": {
"ftp_provision" => {"ftp_provision" => "vsftpd" => "pasv_ip" => "192.168.0.10"}
 },
```

I keep getting syntax errors. All the examples I've been able to see have referenced making JSON files from Ruby DSL with only one level deep of attributes (e.g. `default['key']['value']`) so I'd like to know how to do this correctly per role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll need to use actual JSON for this, and not sure what you mean about one level deep.  this will create a hash 3 or 4 levels deep, depending on how you count it. i haven't seen issues with going further with attributes, and see many cookbooks in the wild with `default['really']['freakin']['long']['strings']['of'] = attributes`

i took a look at chef's examples and they're using ruby's hash format there rather than json, and that method of creating hashes makes rubocop squawk and say it's been deprecated.  i can certainly see how that example would mislead you.

use a linter when building json, here's one https://jsonlint.com/

also I think this may work for you:

```
{
    "ftp_provision": {
        "vsftpd": {
            "pasv_ip": "192.168.0.10"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! By "one level deep" I was referring to the provided examples of JSON where the attribute is simply key:value, and not several long strings of attributes like mine. I just didn't know how to format my long attribute strings into correct json because there were no examples that had long strings as JSON that I could find. Thanks for your help!